# Why does the permanent MUI Drawer overlap the main Box in my ReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In [my test project](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/tree/main/appbar-drawer) the `variant="permanent"` Drawer overlaps the main content:

[image: screenshot]

The ReactJS code in [my custom LeftDrawer.jsx component](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/tree/main/appbar-drawer/src/components) is:

```
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar component="nav">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            MUI
          </Typography>
          <Box>
            {navItems.map((item) => (
              <Button key={item} sx={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                {item}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <nav>
        <Drawer
          container={container}
          variant="permanent"
          open={mobileOpen}
          onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
          ModalProps={{
            // Better open performance on mobile
            keepMounted: true,
          }}
          PaperProps={{
            sx: {
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              width: drawerWidth,
              backgroundColor: "lightblue",
            },
          }}
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
      </nav>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ p: 3 }}>
        <Toolbar />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum...
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

What is causing this overlap please?

I would prefer the 3 areas (the drawer, the app bar, the main content) to coexist peacefully near each other... (unless the window size is `xs`, where I'd like to use `variant="temporary"`)

When looking at [the official Permanent Drawer documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#permanent-drawer), I am not able to see the difference yet. There it works well, nothing overlaps:

[image: screenshot]

I have also tried the following code, which has not helped:

```
  <CssBaseline />
  <AppBar
    position="fixed"
    sx={{ width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`, ml: `${drawerWidth}px` }}
    component="nav"
  >
```